# how could we know this is the last element in the array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code:

```
int array[5] = {1, 0, 1, 0, 0};

int i;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   if(array[i] == 1)
   {
      printf("found one\n");
   }
}
```

how could we know the second `1` in the `array` is the last `1` we found?
I do not mean keep the value of last `1`, what I mean is how should we know the second `1` is the last occurence, no more shows up?

Comment: Maybe you should sort your array first so if you change the value you know that the previous one was the last

Comment: You need to reformulate this. As such, your question is unclear. Do you want this: "Finding the last occurence of integer 1 in a C array"? Or something else? The answer to the title of your question si "the last element of your array is 0".

Comment: yes, it is trying to find the last occurence of 1 in array

Comment: Then how about going from the end and finding the first occurence of 1?

Comment: Look at Maroun Maroun's answer: you loop from the end to the beginning. First occurance of a `1` is by nature the last `1` in the array.

Comment: how about the array is array[5] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0};

Comment: @user2131316 You can break when you find the most-right `1` as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: I am doing it my way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simply loop in a reverse order:

```
for(i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if(array[i] == 1)
   {
      printf("last 1 found!\n");
      //break or do whatever you want
   }
}
```

---

We can further improve the code as follows:

```
int main(){
    int array[] = {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, i;   
    for(i=sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)-1; array[i]!=1 && --i;); 
    printf("last 1 found at index = %d\n", i);
    return 1;
}
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/Z4jE3VaW).

The second form of code has some additional benefits:

- Include initialization.
- Size independence of array.
- Fast in two ways: [Short-circuit behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of  &&, `--i` will be performed when needed.
- Smaller code (removed `if()`, `break`).

Comment: but how about the array is array[5] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0};

Comment: @user2131316 What about it?

Comment: You said "*yes, it is trying to find the last occurence of 1 in array*".

Comment: we can make it like: `for(i=sizeof(a); --i;) if(a[i]) break; printf("fount at %d", i)` bit more fast and size independent.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That implementation was good, could have been an answer though.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan it looks perfect now, sizeof doesn't let anyone bother about putting the size of the array in place , in short it gives a chance to ignore hard coding, correct me if I am wrong. Any way that's  very good implementation , that deserves a +2 because of *editing others post* and second *because of the implementation* . :)

Comment: Editors should also get +10 rep for this kind of edit, wonderful :)

Comment: @PHIfounder Indeed. I usually go to another good answer by the editor and +1 him ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the last index where you found the "1". For example :

```
int array[5] = {1, 0, 1, 0, 0};

int i;
int lastIndexOf=-1;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   if(array[i] == 1)
   {
       lastIndexOf=i;
       printf("found one\n");
   }
}
if(lastIndexOf!=-1)
    printf("last index of 1 : %d\n",lastIndexOf);
```

Comment: You're assuming that there is always a `1` at position `0`. I edited your answer to fix that.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thanks, must've slipped :)

Answer (score 2):

set a counter equal to 0 & increment it every time you find a 1. When the array is completely parsed, you will know which 1 was the last 1.

```
int counter = 0;
int lastone = -1;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   if(array[i]==1)
   {
      counter++;
      lastone = i; 
      printf("found one\n");
   }
}
if(lastone!=-1)
   printf(" %d one is the last one %d", counter, lastone);
```