# For loop enhanced but with ambiguities

Tags: c, for-loop

All I want to know is whether this statement is feasible or not

```
for(j = 2; (j <= i) && flag; j++)
```

`flag` is initialized to `i` before this loop. I have not seen any such thing before.

Comment: Yes possible, give it a try!!

Comment: do i need to end this flag statement with a semi-colon at the end?

Comment: Check [this second pice of code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570791/how-could-we-know-this-is-the-last-element-in-the-array/17570871#17570871)

Comment: Pick a good C book, In for-loop you have three clauses `initialization` `;` condition `;` `increment` So two `;` are needed `(j<=i)&& flag` is nothing but you are combining two conditions as single.

Comment: okay.Thanks.Will see to it.The link was helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general for loop condition is like this:-

```
for(initialization ; condition; increment)
```

So what you are doing is correct.

Breaking down your for loop means:-

```
for(j=2;(j<=i)&& flag ;j++)
```

**initialization** is j=2;

**condition** is (j<=i)&& flag ;

**increment** is j++

One example:-

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    int j = 100;
    for(int i = 1; i<=100/2 && j>100/2; i++){
        sum += i+j;
        j--;
    }

    return sum;

}
```

Second Example with `flag`:

Remember [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), In bubble sort we need two nested loops, outer loop runs for number of passes and inner loop do swapping task for each pair `a[i], a[i + 1]`. To save execution we can make use of some flag variable. If in some pass no swapping done this means no need to execute next pass and sorting completeed, read: [Optimizing bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort):

Now code for this:

```
FLAG = 1;
for(i = 0; FLAG && (i < n - 1); i++){//If flag = ), break outer loop sorting done
  FLAG = 0; // set flag = 0
  for(j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++){
   if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1]){
    swap(arr[j], arr[j + 1]);
    FLAG = 1; // if any swapping need, then check in next round  
   }
 }
}
```

Notice outer loop condition `FLAG && (i < n - 1)`, I think this is what you wants. Hope this help!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan:- Does that make it better? Although I think this is not the best example but this one came to my mind! ;)

Comment: the major concern is when flag is placed inside condition,then in main code it is ended with a semi-colon statement later on in the code.Will that be correct ?

Comment: for(j=2;(j<=i)&& flag ;j++) { if(!(i%j)){if(i%j==0){;}}}

Comment: @ashi200 I think this should answer, Check new example added.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Thanks a lot bro..This is really what i wanted to know.i have marked this as answer as salutation.

Comment: void primePrint(int num) 
{ 
    
    int i,x,flag,j; 
    for (i=2;i<=num;i++) 
    { 
    flag=1; 
        for(j=2;(j<=i)&& flag ;j++) 
        { 
          if(i!=j)  
           {  
           if(i%j) 
                ; 
            else  
                flag=0; 
            } 
            } 
      if(flag) 
          if(i==num) 
            printf("%d",i); 
          else 
              printf("%d,",i);   
     
    } 
}

Comment: the semi-colon after if(i%j) is correct ?